# Can I run an Android emulator on a computer with an AMD processor?

Tags: android-emulator, processor

I was trying to create an Android emulator on my computer but the AVD Manager is telling me that my computer doesn't support a required feature for the "VT-x or SVM." My computer has a AMD A6-5350M processor with radeon graphics with 8GB of memory. I was wondering if there was any way to run an emulator with this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it seems that the state of enabling and disabling the virtualization on my computer is flipped in the BIOS. While trying to run the emulator did succeed is getting to the home screen when the virtualization was actually enabled, it was too slow to actually try to run anything from the Android AVD manager so my CPU itself is to blame. However I did manage to get a decent emulator running with Genymotion's free edition after discovering the fault in the BIOS.

You can download the free genymotion from the link:
https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

Answer (score 2):

VT-x is the Intel virtualization technology while SVM is its equivalent for AMD.

I think either your computer doesn't have such feature or it is not enabled.

Go to the BIOS and see if it is supported.

If the feature is not supported, you can test your app with ADB though.

Comment: It seems that my computer supports it since the option for virtualization is was in the BIOS but it was disabled. After enabling it and retrying the emulator the same message of not having the required features is still there.

Answer (score 0):

My Laptop has also got AMD processor, I tried with Android emulator many times but always get it running slow or not opening at all... So I switched to other Android emulators and I found "Xamarin" cool.. even Genymotion is cool but not all feature you get for fee :P.
So what I suggest is to use "Xamarin".